# ¿en que punto una funcion synchronized cuando hay un wait y un notify el mutex se abre?

Tags: java, hilos

en una funcion como esta

```java
Condition=false;
public void sinchronized mifuncion(){
    while(!Condition){
        try{
            wait();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Interrupcion")

        }
        Condition=false;
        //entrego dato o hago lo que sea (para el)al otro thread
        //que sera identico salvo que testeara Condition=true;
        notifyAll();

    }
}
```

¿en que momento se deja el mutex ?por que lo que yo veo es que si se hace asi
 Condition sera false para cuando se abandone el mutex y nunca se saldra
de ello

Comment: Si nada pone condition a true, el bucle es infinito